# Internet Explorer and Base64 image display

Tags: javascript, base64

In aim to manipulate more easily various images on client side with Javascript, I wrote a function on server side (in VB 2010) to convert a file into a base64 string that I send to the client.

When I tried it in Internet Explorer 8.0 with 3 different images, 1 portrait and 2 landscapes, I realized that only the portrait image was displayed entirely, meanwhile both landscape images were truncated (I can see just the upper part of the image).

I thought I had a bug in my conversion function, until I tried my local page with Firefox: every image is perfectly displayed by Firefox.

So there is my question: Is this a well-known bug of Internet Explorer ? If the answer is yes, Is there a well-known remedy for that well-known bug?

Comment: This is a well known, bug, IE has a character limit imposed on all URIs, which means Data Scheme URIs will have some content truncated.

Comment: In addition to Andrew Dunn's comment your better off using a file system or a database (like SQL 2008 that you have dedicated to serving images). I dont think your going to come close to the compression of protocols such as jpg, gif, png. Also I've found using a Virtual Path Provider to serve up images from a dB is much slower than a file system so I recommend rethinking your design.

Answer (score 14):

IE8 can only do Base64 URI images up to 32kb in size. It's a marginally annoying limitation, but you can still get by with icons/etc. Keep in mind that Base64 encoded images are on average 33% more data sent down the pipe anyway, so it's... eh, y'know, use your judgement.

For anyone interested, it's also possible to make these work in IE6/7 (without, I might add, that 32kb limit...): http://venodesigns.net/2010/06/17/you-got-your-base64-in-my-css/

Comment: thanks for your answer. Well do you mean that base64 encoding is useless in my case? Could i just send the jpeg image as a simple string and declare that string as I do for base64, just replacing
"<img alt='BB' src='data:image/jpg;base64,"
by.. Well by what, by the way?

Comment: You can't replace it by anything. What you could do is create a MHTML file (MIME HTML). These files can contain MIME types of different objects. So the MHTML file can contain a HTML file in normal text encoding, plus images in base64 encoding, and there is no 32KB limit here.

Comment: This happens in IE 11 for me as well.I am opening base64 image in a new tab whose size is around 20 KB but it wont render.The length of string is 27834 chars

Answer (score 4):

IE8 is limited to 32KB. One way around this is to just serve the images in 'tiles' where each tile is less than 32KB.