# outputting image content type using two functions

Tags: php

I'm using an image outside of my docroot and want to display that image inside of a function.

How do I correctly do this?

Here is what I have so far: (Both functions are in the same file)

```
function page(){
  echo'
    test<br />
    '.output().'
  ';
}

function output(){
    header("Content-Type: image/gif");
    readfile( '../../../dirOutsideDocRoot/test.gif' );
}
```

This currently will output the image but I am not able to see the "test" above it. Is it possible to get the image into the page function using `header`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final content you send to the client can have one content-type only. **Either image or text**. If you want both in a single page, **(when image isn't written to file)** you could write the image in base64 in the following way:

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
```

**In your case,**

```
data:image/gif;base64,<base64_encoded_image>
```

See **[Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)**

---

Something like the following will work: (**Untested**)

```
$img = fread(fopen($path, "r"), filesize($path));
$base64 = "data:image/gif;base64," . base64_encode($img);
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that IE only displays half of the image. When I use header, the image displays correctly in all browsers.

Comment: @user1709311 Display the text separately, don't echo it along with image content, and keep the encoding `image/gif` if you want just the image.

Comment: Displaying the test separately still doesn't work. Once I call the functin that has the header function in it, whatever else I want to echo is overridden by the header. In other words, is it possible to save the image in a variable and then pass it?

Comment: Or, can you give me an example of what you're talking about? Please?

Comment: @user1709311 See updated answer. Also, `file_get_contents` can also be used to store image data in a variable, that you can later echo out.

Comment: OK, Cthulhu, thanks for that! Then, I would use `$base64` in the img tag, correct?

Comment: @user1709311 Yes, that is correct. `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,encoded_value" />`

Comment: Thanks Cthulhu. One issue that I'm still having is that only half of the image is showing in IE

Comment: @user1709311 That seems like an uncommon issue. Are you sure you are echoing only the image and not any other characters, text etc along with it?

Comment: Yes, I am echoing the output of `$base64` from within the first function. Is this not right? Like this: `function page(){
  echo'
    test<br />
    <img src="'.output().'" />
  ';
}`

Comment: @user1709311 Seems correct. Do note, that in this case, the content-type would be `text/html`, not `image/gif`.

Comment: I'm not even using the header function any more. I'm only using the snippet of code you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is to display an image and text on the same page. To do that you will have to make a page that has the text and has an `img` tag pointing to another php page that sends back just the image.

Your `Content-Type` header tells the browser that the entire page is an image. Although, that won't happen either because php will fail saying that data has already been sent so it can't output a header.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: You could also like Cthulhu said, embed the image with base64 like this:

```
function output(){
    $imgbinary = fread(fopen('../../../dirOutsideDocRoot/test.gif', "r"), filesize($filename));
    echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary).'" />';
}
```

For more info about base_64 encoding in php, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php.

Comment: thanks. I've tried this but all I can get on IE is half of the image for some reason.

Comment: How big is the image (in KB)?

Comment: I like what he is saying about echoing the text separately but I'm not sure I understand how this should look.

Comment: @user1709311 You would have to have two php pages. The first page would echo the text and an `img` tag referring to a second page that outputted the image.

Comment: @user1709311 Ah, IE only supports base64 URIs up to 32KB. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159500/internet-explorer-and-base64-image-display.

Comment: OK... Can I reference the second file, the one that outputs the image from within a function? Also, thank you for pointing out that IEs limit is 32k. That explains that...

Answer (score 1):

You should have two php pages:

Page 1:

```
echo'
    test<br /><img src="page2.php"/>';
```

Page 2:

```
header("Content-Type: image/gif");
readfile( '../../../dirOutsideDocRoot/test.gif' );
```