# base64 string image data is not completly displaying in ie8

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have to display an image,which is in base64 string format. It's working fine in ie9,chrome and mozilla.But when using ie8 image is not completly displaying.Due to security purpose i am not able save image on server and user url for displaying image.Is there any other way to display image on ie8.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with the image? It's alot easier to help you, if we can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the answer from Ryan McGrath at [Internet Explorer and Base64 image display](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10159966): IE8 can only show Base64 images up to 32KB in size.

Most likely your image is too large to be handled by IE8.

I don't have the time to write an extensive example right now, but a possible workaround would be to serve the image through another webpage. Read the image into a stream and send it back. For example, you might do something like this:

```
void GetImage(int imageId) {
    byte[] imageData = GetDataFromDatabase(imageId);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData)) {
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```

And then in your webpage you could do something like this:

```
<img src="Image.aspx?GetImage&imageId=1"/>
```

***Note:*** All of the this is non-working code and possibly contains typos and non-existing methods. But it's just an idea to get you started. If you perform a Google search for "C# + asp.net output image" you get a whole bunch of results with working code samples, such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database.

Comment: It's true.can you suggest any alternative solution.Image strored in my database as byte format.How can i display image compactable in all browsers.