# IE 11 not displaying embedded base 64 images

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-11

I have exported a docx file through Libre Office into XHTML and it encodes the images in base 64:

```
<img style="height:0.647cm;width:0.743cm;" alt="" src="data:image/*;base64,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"/>
```

Here is the corresponding [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/icc97/7ou5gju1/).

Things I've tried:

1. **The image isn't corrupt.** This displays the image fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 11.
2. **The image is less than 32 KB.** I've read similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159500/internet-explorer-and-base64-image-display) on IE not displaying these images, but there the problem is over 32 KB, and the images I'm using are 1 KB. Plus there is a [4 GB limit for IE 11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) so it's not that.
3. Setting `height` and `width` attributes explicitly made no difference.

Comment: `image/*` is not a valid MIME type for an image. Mismatched MIME types are grounds for a resource being blocked as suspicious by the browser's security policies.

Comment: I had a similar issue in IE11. It is incredible that Chrome, Opera and Firefox accept this format typed like this `data:image / png`,but not in IE11. I had to avoid whitespaces striclty  `data:image/png` to make work in IE11

Answer (score 2):

Libre Office outputs the images with `src="data:image/*` but I solved the problem using `src="data:image/png` instead.

Comment: Why are you using Libre Office to make a webpage? o_O

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Because I've got a Help Guide that someone's written in Word and I need to convert it to HTML.

Comment: That's actually the best reason I've heard for that question XD I would say "carry on", but at least consider re-writing it as HTML in the first place rather than relying on automated conversion systems. Word processors are designed to output physical pages, whereas a webpage is far more flexible.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've got a not technical user who's writing the guide and is used to Word. Plus all the other documentation is written in Word. So it makes it hard to suggest other things. I did mention markdown but got a bit of a blank stare :)