# Can vba userform Webbrowser control load base64 image gif

Tags: vba, base64, userform

I want to load base64 image gif to vba webbrowser control by html code, without writing a gif file in the computer.

```
Public Sub testUF()
Dim sBased64_Encoded As String
sBased64_Encoded = _
    "R0lGODlhyADIAPIFAP%2FyAAoKCgAAAcRiAO0cJAAAAAAAAAAAACH%2FC05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh%2BQQJCgAFAC" & _
    "wAAAAAyADIAAAD%2F1i63P4wykmrvTjrzbv%2FYCiOZGmeaKqubOu%2BcCzPdG3feK7vfO%2F%2FwKBwSCwaj8ikcslsOp%2FQ" & _
    "qHRKrVqv2Kx2y%2B16v%2BCweEwum8%2FotHrNbrvf8Lh8Tq%2Fb7%2Fi8fs%2Fv%2B%2F%2BAgYKDhIWGh4iJiouMjY6PkJGSk" & _
    "5SVlpeYmZqbnJ2en6ChoqOkpaanqKmqq6ytrq%2BwsbKztLW2t7i5uru8vb6%2FwMHCw8TFxsfIycrLzM3Oz9DR0tPU1dbX2Nna2" & _
    "9zd3t%2Fg4eLj5OXmkwLpAszq68vt7OrI7QH1AfDD9Pb4wvr1%2FMH83ZP3S6C9gemAGdxH0NfCfw17PUTozqG6gwcBkph4EP" & _
    "%2FSRI0jONrzeBEjxIQnRNYjmc7kyYolVAZgKcAlRRDt2gHYybPnzo6PPkbkkFOdz6MAgDoSitJD0XRIfSptxBQm0adRe05lpBMpS" & _
    "Atds2bduiisz68VzIo9SlaRWp5oKbxdy7NtorkA4k7AS9cumKeAA9vMiNXr0L1G6a71%2ByWw45yDGRaNqtcBX8U%2FR555zLlm" & _
    "ZIp4Kze4jJmxl86PP4NOfFQ0A9KKTWeReRCzbcNNI8C%2BLRsLbXu3g8M9bJm1cKS9r%2Fyudzy46N22k1tZHqD57efGrdfVbEam" & _
    "VuDazxIvAF249NklI39nHr4n2vLBz%2FtOP3h99fbDc7%2FOjj%2Fzys3%2F9NlkX387vcdff%2FJtgVpL4PVnIFTHqQbHgp6x5%2BB4" & _
    "8Nln04QL1kbggwI0J%2BEbFHp4oX4LZLhdZICYiJ9sZg0g4wD2MeJiezAaNyONK860yI3h5QjhTjvW%2BGODL3Knm44zGqmIi6Ed" & _
    "mJSSELSz45UzJqgHlFLiJaQAWGKpZR5cDimemU4umU6YV46JR5kh4hYnW1Q%2BYCWbWdZpyEEE9EnAbX7%2B2SOFd4qpZyF8%2BgmoooM" & _
    "SumaYbt6RaJ%2BLUtqoo2xGasekgmIWqH2OPmrof44AqV2RPKEqlqZ9mGqdqgDAGhWrfLjaHKyyIneojUi2h2uTi%2B36iGq3%2FSpjX" & _
    "8KW%2Blmxh8AS2exYyTZCrG3G8rhqtLyqR%2B2zudJJaie2EpgmJ%2BGK65%2BPnpRrLq2HqCsuu3v2aq636IIr77zjbuIugfAiei%2B%2" & _
    "B54LiooA9DuxSvpoYbJKGSBIc8CcKY8SwhVMu3KPADR9ccMYWPyyKXSAf6pq%2Bh4b87X4oflzyyienOB7GLStgcr0oW%2FVEAgAh" & _
    "%2BQQJCgAFACwsAHwAbABMAAAD%2F1i63P4wPkGFvDjrzXO1XSiOJPSVaKpK5%2Bq%2B4RfMQQvfOCPTdu6%2Fu1nvR0QFa5" & _
    "WiUnSkISnL6KbJS0qvrIrTOcR6FVSh9UsuhJ%2Bg29n5PXdXa1pbuxVDcfHZnFK3p2F5AXsCfWgpHx8AiouMimxebmMkiBWNlgCPW" & _
    "JF3JZQUl42ZV5t%2FI54CoIyiUomXbx6VqbKrUa2Wrxi2spe0S7qMuBe%2Fu6pykLG3khzDxI7GYKfRlIVcnqDBDszNxXoL0t901Gja2A3a" & _
    "287d0ODS4n7kysLI6Jai7N%2Fu4%2FPA8Vmf9Lyq8MlHA6BBAOXOHaw2kGCAgwAT7oO4iCEhhw8pbpP4T%2F8jNzQYM3rcxRHVyI" & _
    "rPzISj9vHkolcKNdpbWailS4T9VHa8mU6QN5p9bLqEOdHlzIYsUc7gSXQnz1462TlhmjNmqny57l1cerOpSYNY5d2b2rVq0WZh%2FUk" & _
    "tWJaTubPE0qogazSliXkD8g74KIXuSag68OrlG8XvSMA%2Fd%2Brdq9TnEsMeEa%2F7CmAx4cdsFcFz2jgrhcWg9UqG4Xcz5csRPoQO" & _
    "PfpF6bPaRqtevbi1i9ecNZ%2BVXYF2bbtEnBAYToAe8eKNtSKibXuFcOLGoSdX3nt187k0jkcf%2FpF6ddbAfzznjk77dO%2FMwyuBrNHyIvez1PfN" & _
    "fBJ%2B5cG7rudgT9G%2BfVCl%2BuHAH0T%2B4RefOmUskA89BeYVl3xeLIhOg4wd6FiCCki4DYUPIoihhs1wmB%2BEGGZIH08Aklji" & _
    "gCj2VOIFLLYYIBYxojjjFTU%2BpeKHJ7YYyo4J5njTjfNx5WNAHr7YgF81NcZkUJ0pCcGTdXxE5RaoScnAlVzS16SLWjrQpZGYQNnTlWF" & _
    "KANWa6pWTZgFsJmminFG9iUGcF27ZZk52Kqgenne5NUICACH5BAUKAAUALDAAfABsAEwAAAP%2FWLrc%2FjA%2BQYW8OOvN"
sBased64_Encoded = sBased64_Encoded & _
    "c7VdKI4k9JVoqkrn6r7hF8xBC984I9N27r%2B7We9HRAVrlaJSdKQhKcvopslLSq%2BsitM5xHoVVKH1Sy6En6Db2fk9d1drWlu7FUNx8" & _
    "dmcUrenYXkBewJ9aCkfHwCKi4yKbF5uYySIFY2WAI9YkXcllBSXjZlXm38jngKgjKJSiZdvHpWpsqtRrZavGLayl7RLuoy4F7%2B7qnKQsb" & _
    "eSHMPEjsZgp9GUhVyeoMEOzM3FegvS33TUaNrYDdrbzt3Q4NLifuTKwsjolqLs3%2B7j88DxWZ%2F0vKrwyUcDoEEA5c4drDaQYICD" & _
    "ABPug7iIISGHDyluk%2FhP%2FyM3NBgzetzFEdXIis%2FMhKP28eSiVwo12ltZqKVLhP1UdryZTpA3mn1suoQ50eXMhixRzuBJdCfPXjr" & _
    "ZOWGaM2aqfLnuXVx6s6lJg1jl3ZvatWrRZmH9SS1YlpO5s8TSqiBrNKWJeQPyDvgohe5JqDrw6uUbxe9IwD936t2r1OcSwx4Rr%2FsKY" & _
    "DHhx2wVwXPaOCuFxaD1SobhdzPlyxE%2BhA49%2BkXps9pGq169uLWL15w1n5VdgXZtu0ScEBhOgB7x4o21IqJte4Vw4" & _
    "sahJ1fee3XzuTSORx%2F%2BkXp11sB%2FPOeOTvt078zDK4Gs0fIi97PU9818En7lwbuu52BP0b59UKX64cAfRP7hF586ZSyQDz0F5hWX" & _
    "fF4siE6DjB3oWIIKSLgNhQ8iiKGGzXCYH4QYZkgfTwCSWOKAKPZU4gUsthggFjGiOOMVNT6l4ocnthjKjgnmeNON83HlY0AevtiAXzU1x" & _
    "mRQnSkJwZN1fETlFqhJycCVXNLXpItaOtClkZhA2dOVYUoA1ZrqlZNmAWwmaaKcUb2JQZwXbtlmTnYqqB6ed7k1QgIAOw%3D%3D"
Dim sHTMLBody As String
sHTMLBody = "about:<html><body><img src='data:image/gif;base64," & sBased64_Encoded & "'></body></html>"
Dim o As New UserForm1
With o.Controls.Add("Shell.Explorer.2")
    .Navigate2 sHTMLBody
End With
o.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

The webbrowser show "Cannot reach this page". The HTML code has been tested successfully if I put into html file and load in a browser.

May someone please tell me what is doing wrong or if it is doable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That webbrowser control is based on Internet Explorer which has been deprecated. You may need to find an alternative method - e.g. Selenium

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After I search for your idea, and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159500/internet-explorer-and-base64-image-display suggesting ie support base64 32kb below. The html code is about 10kb only. So it may be still doable somehow. Am I correct?

Comment: I doubt it - that question is from 2012 - 10 years before IE was deprecated in 2022

Comment: It does work if I changed the based64 value to R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////
wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML
wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a limit to the length of a URL in IE (around 2k characters?) - try this instead.

```
'...
'...
    Dim sHTMLBody As String
    sHTMLBody = "<img src='data:image/gif;base64," & sBased64_Encoded & "'>"
    Dim o As New UserForm1
    With o.Controls.Add("Shell.Explorer.2")
        .Navigate2 "about:blank"
        While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.Body.innerHTML = sHTMLBody
    End With
    o.Show vbModeless
```

...or using DOM methods

```
    '...
    '...
    Dim imgSrc As String
    imgSrc = "data:image/gif;base64," & sBased64_Encoded
    Dim o As New UserForm1, img As Object
    With o.Controls.Add("Shell.Explorer.2")
        .Navigate2 "about:blank"
        While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Wend

        Set img = .document.createElement("img")
        img.src = imgSrc
        .document.Body.appendChild img
    End With
    o.Show vbModeless
```

You could more-conveniently store your b64 string by pasting it into a worksheet somewhere...

Comment: Tested the DOM method and it works too. Thank you.